# How to implement a query that retrieves data from multiple services in a microservice architecture?

Tags: microservices

You have applied the Microservices architecture pattern and the Database per service pattern. As a result, it is no longer straightforward to implement queries that join data from multiple services. Also, if you have applied the Event sourcing pattern then the data is no longer easily queried.
What is the way(s) in which we can retrieve the data from multiple services?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally needed join between multiple microservices' DB should not be complex one. It should be easy one. Easy to achieve the join by in-memory manipulation of data.

If that is not case with your system, then you can use CQRS pattern of Event Sourcing. And join should be apply on read view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and look at the below article that explains data replication issues in Microservices.

***Copied from below URL source*** :

> **Selective data replication** allows you to use data from another microservice whilst minimizing the scope of the dependency.
> Microservices using this approach are dependent on the schema of their
> microservice dependencies (and data replication support); they are not
> dependent on the remote API of those microservices. This minimises the
> cost of the microservice dependency in development and production.

For further reading , [Check this](https://medium.com/@john_freeman/querying-data-across-microservices-8d7a4667668a)